# Write data frame to csv file with special requirements

Tags: python, csv

I am a beginner in python.

I need to convert a list to a CSV file with special requirements.

I have a list like this:

```
text1 = [('CIF', '48752614P'), ('BILL', '87451,45')]
text2 = [('CLIENT', 'JOHN'), ('MONEY', '450'), ('HOUSE','2541')]
text3 = [('NAME', 'MERY'), ('CIF', ['47852361N','4587563O'])]
```

and I want to write (export) it to an ONE csv file. I mean, something like this:

```
text1   CIF         BILL
        48752614P   87451,45
text2   CLIENT      MONEY       HOUSE
        JOHN        450         2541
text3   NAME        CIF
        MERY        [47852361N, 4587563O]
```

What did I do?
First I pased the list to a Data Frame and then I write it to a csv_file:

```
text_files = [text1, text2, text3]
df_results = []

for file in text_files:
   df_results = pd.DataFrame(file)
   df_results = df_results.T
   df_results.to_csv((str(file) + '.csv'), sep=';', encoding='utf-8', index=False, quotechar=' ', header=False)
```

So, my problem is that I want to write all of them in only one CSV file.

I want:

```
text1   CIF         BILL
        48752614P   87451,45
text2   CLIENT      MONEY       HOUSE
        JOHN        450         2541
text3   NAME        CIF
        MERY        [47852361N, 4587563O]
```

I have been searching, but I do not find how to solve this problem.

Thanks,

MARCUS

Comment: I think your main issue here is that you are not writing a csv file, so you'll have to come up with your own way of writing the output since it is pretty custom as far as I know

Comment: I think you need to rethink your structure. This is not something you put in a DataFrame. DataFrames are tables with rows and columns that you do operations on and not a general dump object (my opinion).

Comment: @AntonvBR yes, I was thinking about using a dictionary. But, in that case I think it is correct to use a DataFrame too. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for -

```
import pandas as pd

text1 = [('CIF', '48752614P'), ('BILL', '87451,45')]
text2 = [('CLIENT', 'JOHN'), ('MONEY', '450'), ('HOUSE','2541')]
text3 = [('NAME', 'MERY'), ('CIF', ['47852361N','4587563O'])]

col_num = max([len(text) for text in texts])

texts = [text1,text2,text3]
for text in texts:
    if len(text) < col_num:
        text.extend([(None,None)*(col_num-len(text))])

col_values = [[] for i in range(col_num)]
[col_values[i].extend([text[i][0],text[i][1]]) for text in texts for i in range(len(text))]
df = pd.DataFrame(col_values).T
df.fillna('')
df.index = ['text1','text1','text2','text2','text3','text3']
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but do you know how to split the columns. I mean, now, all the results are in one column, there is any way to do that? Thank you

Comment: All are in one column? I get two columns and the `text1` etc form the index of the dataframe. Run the code I pasted and once thats done check `df.shape`. What do you get?

Comment: (6,2) Yes, it is correct. But when open it through the Excel, there is only one column. I tink that is a stupid question, but I don not how to solve it.

Comment: @MarcRusiñol It can be your Excel setting. Change df.to_csv('output.csv') to **df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=";")**

Comment: I get the correct output. Are you changing the defaults or something else? Are you using `xlsx` or `xls` as the output extension?

Comment: Hi, it is not solved yet, because I have cases with different length, and two or more values. ('CIF', ['47852361N','4587563O'])] look at my question, i edit it.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in comments you don't need a dataframe for this.
Updated with ; and skip first column after duplicate.

```
text1 = [('CIF', '48752614P'), ('BILL', '87451,45')]
text2 = [('CLIENT', 'JOHN'), ('MONEY', '450'), ('HOUSE','2541')]
text3 = [('NAME', 'MERY'), ('CIF', ['47852361N','4587563O'])]

with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    for ind, item in enumerate([text1,text2,text3]):
        for ind2, subitem in enumerate(item):
            if ind2 == 0:
                outstring = "text{};{}".format(str(ind+1),(';'.join([str(i) for i in subitem])))
            else:
                outstring = ";{}".format((';'.join([str(i) for i in subitem])))
            f.write(outstring)
            print(outstring)
```

Outputs:

```
text1;CIF;48752614P
;BILL;87451,45
text2;CLIENT;JOHN
;MONEY;450
;HOUSE;2541
text3;NAME;MERY
;CIF;['47852361N', '4587563O']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but do you know how to put the output structure as I said before? I

Comment: @MarcRusiñol Not exactly sure what you are asking for but I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @AntonvBR, it is not solved yet, because I have cases with different length, and two or more values. ('CIF', ['47852361N','4587563O'])] look at my question, i edit it.

Comment: @MarcRusiñol Updated, but your data strucutre is a mess :D

Comment: Thank you. Yes I know that this is not the perfect data structure, but this text lists are extracted from reading some PDF's. So, there are PDF's with information that others dont have. Anyway, I have a little mess, yes

Comment: @MarcRusiñol If you got what you wanted you should consider marking this or another answer as answered. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To organize the data into the required structure there are two steps to be done:
1) zip each list of tupels by their indices - transform [(a, b), (a', b')] into [(a, a'), (b, b')]  - First row in the code.
2) iterate on all lists(in the original question [text1, text2, text3]) and get all zipped tupels as one flat list with their relevant original text index. Second row in the code.

This makes putting the data into a dataframe and exporting simple. Third and fourth rows of the code.

```
one_text = lambda text: [x for x in zip(*text)]
data_for_df = [ [i] + list(text) for i in range(0, len(all_texts)) for text in one_text(all_texts[i])]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_for_df, columns=['text_name', 'col1', 'col2'])
df.to_csv(target_file)
```